# How is the access to field synchronized

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++-coroutine, seastar

I'm looking at this snippet from [seastar tutorial](https://docs.seastar.io/master/split/5.html#concurrency-in-coroutines):

```c++
#include <seastar/core/coroutines.hh>
#include <seastar/coroutine/parallel_for_each.hh>

seastar::future<bool> all_exist(std::vector<sstring> filenames) {
    bool res = true;
    co_await seastar::coroutine::parallel_for_each(filenames, [&res] (const seastar::sstring& name) -> seastar::future<> {
        res &= co_await seastar::file_exists(name);
    });
    co_return res;
}
```

I'm learning advanced C++, I suspect there is a race in this code. The `&=` operator is in fact two operations, read and write, and it's not atomic. The lambda captures `res` by reference and multiple threads modify it in parallel. This scenario can happen:

- both threads `A` and `B` read `true` from `res`
- thread `A` writes `false`
- thread `B`, not seeing the write by `A`, overwrites it back to `true`

Is the above scenario possible? If not, why not?

Comment: That highly depends on how parallel the `couroutine::parallel_for_each` function is. "async" code does not suffer from memory-based race conditions, "threaded" code does. In any case, C++ does not detect and protect you against it and I doubt the library either.

Comment: "async" code does not suffer from memory-based race conditions, "threaded" code does -- can you elaborate on that? Async code, in my understanding, is another way of writing a threaded code.

Comment: By async I meant "cooperative multitasking" and by "threaded", "preemptive multitasking". For the former, the code is in charge when it yields CPU to other code, so unless you would put `co_yield` statement between the read and write, the operation is "atomic". For the latter, the code can be interrupted at any CPU instruction which means *anywhere*, including between the read and write. The user has to explicitly create critical sections which cannot be interrupted by other task.

Comment: Yes, coroutines could be scheduled e.g. to a thread-pool so they are "threaded", or there could be just a single global event loop that can only switche tasks on `co_yield` statements. So as I said, it depends on how parallel the function truly is. I unfortunately have no experience with `seastar` library.

Comment: coroutines don't enforce the work to be done in the same thread, it depends on the executor, which is `seastar::coroutine::parallel_for_each` which seems to run the code in the same threads, i think you should learn about coroutines first and how they work before looking at libraries.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the answer: `parallel_for_each` schedules all subtasks on the same shard (i.e. the same CPU core). So there are no two cores executing the `&=` operation. I just find the name confusing, there are `parallel_for` functions elsewhere in C++ which execute on multiple threads. Single-threaded execution shouldn't be called _parallel_, even though it's a co-routine.

Answer (score 0):

The `seastar::coroutine::parallel_for_each` method, [according to documentation](https://docs.seastar.io/master/group__future-util.html#gaf687b5637cac1ef4c74c1d5344c86974), processes all elements in a single shard (i.e., a single thread). So no synchronization is necessary.

The parallelism comes from executing using coroutines - multiple  `file_exists` calls are initiated and wait for their return values in parallel, but the return values are processed by a single thread.

The name is a bit confusing, elsewhere "parallel" means "multiple threads", e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrency-namespace-functions?view=msvc-170#parallel_for_each) or [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html).